# Peoplepicker get all users in tenant

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, people-picker

How can I get all of the users in my tenant? I get just the users in a group.

This is my code:

```
private _getPeoplePickerItems(items: any[]) {
    console.log('Items:', items);

  }

public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    return (
  <PeoplePicker
                context={this.props.context}
                titleText="People Picker"
                personSelectionLimit={1}

                showtooltip={true}
                isRequired={false}
                disabled={false}
                selectedItems={this._getPeoplePickerItems}
                showHiddenInUI={false}
                principleTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
                defaultSelectedUsers={[this.props.mailProp]} />
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all the users then you can leave the "GroupName" attribute in the control blank.

https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/